# How to change the current directory to a designated directory using chdir() in c?

Tags: c, chdir, getenv

*EDIT*

The existed directory is not necessarily a sub-directory of the home directory. It can be a sub-directory of a sub-directory of the home directory.

*End of EDIT*

I am reading a user input (e.g., cd existedDirectory) to change the current directory to the "existedDirectory". I know that

```
chdir(getenv("HOME"));
```

can change the current directory to home directory, so I tried the following methods:

```
chdir(getenv("/existedDirectory"));
chdir(getenv("existedDirectory"));
chdir(getenv("~/existedDirectory"));
chdir("/existedDirectory");
chdir("existedDirectory");
chdir("~/existedDirectory");
```

Nothing worked. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The 4th and 5th things you tried will work if the directory exisits.  The others do not.

Comment: You first need to learn what `getenv` does.

Comment: `HOME` is an environment variable, and `getenv("HOME")` gets it's value which is a string representing your home directory. Things like `"/existedDirectory"` is already a directory name. It's not an environment variable. Therefore, it makes no sense to call `getenv("/existedDirectory")`.

Comment: `chdir` changes the working directory of the process executing it and does not affect the parent shell process. If that is not your problem, show a [mre].

Comment: Thank you for all of your comments. Now I understand that to use `getenv()` I need a full path, just like `HOME` instead of a directory's name. (If I misunderstood the concept, please let me know.) Unfortunately, the 4th and 5th did not work when I print the current directory using `getcwd`. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you ***know*** it didn't work?  What test did you use for success/failure?

Answer (score 3):

`chdir` takes a string argument with a path to change to.  It does no other special handling (environment vars or home or anything else), so you if you want any of those things, you need to build a string to pass into it.

```
chdir("/existingDirectory");
```

which change to and existing directory *in the root directory* -- it has an absolute path.  So it has to be one of the directories you see when you run `ls /`.

```
chdir("exisitingDirectory");
```

will change to an existing subdirectory of the current director.

If you want to change to a subdirectory of your home directory, you need something like:

```
char path[PATH_MAX];
sprintf(path, "%s/%s", getenv("HOME"), "subdir");
chdir(path);
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Actually, the code gives me a segmentation fault. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Which code gives the segmentation fault?  Use a debugger to determine where the fault is occurring.  Of the above code, the only possible segmentation fault is if `$HOME` is not defined in your environment.

Answer (score 2):

`chdir()` in C only affects the process, which calls it. Your shell and your program are two different processes, which run separately. So, the environmental variable $PWD, which indicates the working directory, will only be changed for your application. Check [this resource](https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/chdir-in-c-language-with-examples/amp/), too.

> Note:`chdir()` doesn’t change the working directory of current shell. Because when the program is executed in the shell, the shell follows fork on exec mechanism. So, it doesn’t affect the current shell.

Comment: BTW, check lurker's comment. getenv() is not the function you need. There is no sense in using it that way

Comment: Hey, Chris Dodd's solution isn't a full one and does not catch the main idea. And chdir("~/existingDirectory") can do the job as well

Comment: Thank you for your comment. When I print the current directory using `getcwd`, but unfortunately it did not work. Any ideas?

Comment: I didn't catch that. What do you mean?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. When I typed `chdir("~existingDirectory");` and `printf("%s\n", getcwd(cd, 100));`, to print out the current directory, I could see the original path rather than a changed path. I was thinking that maybe `printf("%s\n", getcwd(cd, 100));` is wrong but I was not sure why.

Comment: You omitted a slash there. It's ~/existingDirectory

Comment: Thank you again for your comment. I also tried with the slash, but it unfortunately did not work...